# Remove the previous view and show only the current view in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I m new to iphone programmming and could not understand where I'm going wrong.

How to show only the current view and remove all other views?
Because when I click on one of tab bar item to load a `newview`, it is showing `prevoiusview` in background and present view on the top of it .Because of this the screen is looking blurred.
How to fix this?

Comment: when you add your new view. remove the previous view. using this [<uiview_name> removefromsuperview];

Comment: What do you mean screen is looking blurred? Make sure you have a background color on each view controller linked to the tab bar, also ensure alpha is set to 1.0. The tab bar controller should deal with controlling the view hierarchy. If you removefromsuperview as suggested above you could risk a reference error when the user touches the previous tab. You will also lose the saved state between tabs, unless this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this before you add new view:

```
for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are create `UIView` each time the `UITabBar` action performed.

```
[view removeFromSuperview];
```

if you want to remove all added items in self.view

```
for (id view in self.view) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

otherwise use

```
view.hidden=TRUE;
```